# Viewing Data From Transactional Tests - Hibernate + Spring + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, automated-tests

I have a bunch of tests in a Hibernate/Spring application. Yesterday, I transitioned them from using the JUnit 3.8 base test class provided by Spring to the JUnit 4.4 one.

Everything works great, because now, my tests are wrapped in transactions, and data created/modified is automatically rolled back (instead of me writing code to delete newly-created entities).

The only problem is that **I cannot peek into the database during test execution.** If a test fails, I often add breakpoints near the end and peer into the MySQL database via SQL Yog to see what's going on. But now, I just see empty tables. (I mean in integration tests that simulate production very closely and actually touch the database.)

I tried setting the global isolation level to read uncommitted, but it didn't change the fact that I can't see the data. How can I configure Spring/Hibernate to allow me to view the data from another process?

Comment: can you give me your test code ? If there is an error, please write the error to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and found that setting the **session** isolation level while using YOG sometimes helped.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

This only uncovered another disturbing issue - while running tests, the Hibernate didn't actually run some of the actions unless I used `HibernateTemplate.flush();` after every Hibernate operation.
As this very annoying, I finally set Hibernate so it would always **flush** queries, like this:

```
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

... 

hibernateTemplate.setFlushMode(HibernateTemplate.FLUSH_ALWAYS);
```